# Retrieving javascript output from a form via php

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a hidden field in a form where I'm trying to grab the users screen resolution. Then on the processing end retrieve the screen resolution via php. Unfortunately, my understanding of javascript is pretty limited. Here is what I have. I would really appreciate any help.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function xy(){
            document.write(screen.width + "x" + screen.height);
            document.getElementById('xy').value;
            }           
    </script>
</head>




<form action="" method=post >

    //other fields here

    <input type="hidden" name="xy" id="xy" value=""/>
    <input type=submit name="button" value="button" /> 
</form>
```

When I view the page's source code, shouldn't I see the value set to for example "1366x768"? Now on the processing side, I would like to pull out information with php like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['xy']) && (!empty($_POST['xy'])){
 $blah = $_POST['xy'];
 //sanatize $blah;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setResolution()
    {
        document.getElementById('xy').value = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
    }
</script>
```

Then, on submit, make sure the function is executed

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="button" onclick="setResolution()" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, onsubmit should do the same as onclick, right?

Comment: @ulliw That will take you less than a minute to test. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
function xy(){
    document.getElementById('xy').value = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;

}
```

and use the script tag or execute the function after rendering of the form else the element would not be found

EDITED: added [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptX8F/)

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and the useful fiddle. It makes a lot of sense, but still doesn't work for me.

Comment: hmm sorry no idea besides... fiddle works and is sending the data :(

Answer (score 1):

ulliw,

you don't call the function so you don't get anything...

if you will change to this, i beleive it will work for you:

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        document.write(screen.width + "x" + screen.height); //this will write on the html page 
        document.getElementById('xy').value=screen.width + "x" + screen.height; // this will put the resolution in your form's hidden field
</script>
```